# Chow-Lin Time Series Disaggregation

Tags: r, time-series, arima, disaggregation

Hy, I am working on a time series with yearly observations starting from 1995. Since I wanted to forecast the next values with ARIMA methods, I thought it was more appropriate to get quarterly data through the td function in R with the chow-lin-maxlog method. I have been looking online, but I do not find exhaustive literature about the Chow Lin disaggregation technique and neither on its assumptions: how can I judge if the quartely data aren't just creating more noise for the estimation of the ARIMA model?
Any help is appreciated!